# Как в qlabel добавить новую строчку с переносом без удаление старой?

Tags: c++, qt

Как в qlabel добавить новую строчку без удаление старой? С переносом и без переноса на новую строчку. Так сказать дополнить информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать сеттер свойства `text` вместе с имеющимся текстом, например:

без переноса

```
label->setText(label->text() + " some added text");
```

или с переносом

```
label->setText(label->text() + "\nsome added text");
```

---

UPD

Добавить число можно с помощью `QString::number`

```
double magicNumber = 42;
label->setText(label->text() + "\nsome added text\n" + QString::number(magicNumber));
```

Документация https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number

Comment: А как можно преобразовать число int, float в строку и вывести в label ?

Comment: @zhilenkov отредактировал ответ